# Transferring static class variables in Java?

Tags: java, methods, static, class-variables, jcreator

This is a game where you jst randomly walk around a maze and find items so that you can fight the boss.

The entire code is about 350 lines so I've pulled out the relevant parts. But the problem is that "items" isn't working and when the "monster" method is used it just ignores it. (Sorry for swedish comments)

//The static

```
public class Spel
{
static Rum current;
static Rum rum12 = new Rum("Du hittar ingenting. " , "En väg. ");
static boolean items = false;
```

//Where "visited" is used.

```
    if (current.item1 != null){
        current.visited = true;
        }
        if (current.item2 != null){
        current.visited = true;
        }
        if (current.item3 != null){
        current.visited = true;
```

//Where "items" is checked.

```
  boolean items = ((rum9.visited==true) || (rum2.visited==true) && (rum5.visited==true));
```

//Where I'm trying to use "items".

```
public class monster {

public void rulla1(){
if (Spel.items == false){
System.out.println("Du behöver hitta 2 objekt för att slåss mot bossen");
Spel.current = Spel.rum12; /
}else
```

Comment: What does "items isn't working" means? It's a variable, what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's not ignored, it is just empty, so it does what you code it to do: nothing.

```
public monster() {
}
```

Maybe you meant to call `rulla1()`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `monster()` is not the ***method*** it's  ***constuctor***.

Secondly it is not doing anything because nothing is written into it , 
**It's Empty**

```
public monster() {
}
```